# Validate and fix a false inputted mathematical expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, eval, regexp-replace

First of all excuse me if there is a topic with such solution here on SOF. I could not find exactly what I searched for and must ask this question.
Long words small mean - back to work.
I wrote a calculator using the following "technology": 
1. the user inputs the data by clicking on buttons. There are +-/* operators at this point of time (will be improved in the future). 
2. The inputted data is being pushed into an array and filtered from duplicate operators (e.g. +++, ---, //, ****) and afterwards joint in a string. 
3. Then the string is being taken by eval() and returns the solution to result span.
Now the problem: at this point of time I wrote by myself a while () "filter", moreover looks like bad "crutch" for my bad code.. 
But this "filter" does not clean up expressions like 2.4.5 or 2.333.444.5555, and eval() begins to send me bad messages.
I tried to fix the case writing a regexp, but I failed.

So guys if you have a regexp which will filter and return pure mathexpression or at least know a link to such a regexp, I will appreciate it much.
The link to my calculator(http://mrfreeman16.000webhostapp.com/Calcul/index.html).

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to provide such validation on the input level, preventing user from typing such invalid expressions?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help. It is a good idea. But, unfortunately, I dunno which regexp will be suitable.

Comment: You don't need one, use a function, that will run validation by characters. For example, if user clicks "+", check, if last added character is not "+". If it's so, add it, otherwise just do nothing. Makes sense?

Comment: Hmm, good idea, I will try to bring it to life, thanks.